# How to get particles to move with object. Works in 2.79 not in 2.8 possible bug?

Tags: animation, particles, keyframes, collision

Seems like a pretty straightforward question.
I am using blender 2.8, and had trouble for days trying to figure out why my particles escape my collision object once the collision object begins a keyframed movement.

I decided to simplify the whole thing to test it. I made a sphere, keyframed it to move along x axis, and assigned it as a collision object. Made a square inside the sphere, keyframed the same movement. Then added emitter particles to it.

Now in blender 2.79, the particles collide and move with the sphere, none escape. I saved the file, and opened it in 2.8, and the exact same thing has a different outcome. The particles stay at the source (escaping the collision object), while some follow. [image]

Is this a bug? If so, how do I go about fixing it, and is there a workaround for my project? I require snow inside a snow globe, to stay inside the snow globe once I start animating it. In 2.8 It isn't working, and I can't open a 2.8 file in 2.79

Thanks

Comment: FYI, I've filed a bug on this at https://developer.blender.org/T71620.

Comment: Thanks! Will keep an eye out on it!